# How much clearance through air is required for 10 kV DC?

Tags: voltage, high-voltage, clearance

Suppose I have two uninsulated connectors with 10 kV DC between them. How much clearance through air should I have between those connectors? What table is this found in?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength)

Comment: You are going to be a lot more specific, according to google (10 * kilovolt) / (3 * (megavolts / m)) =
3.33333333 millimeters, but that is probably not safe for anything, 10x that is probably not safe for humans. What is your application, are you trying to meet a code? is it production or an experiment?

Comment: what altitude ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

General guideline is 7,500~10kV/inch so about 1"/25mm **through the air**, assuming the parts are not pointy and high altitude is not a possibility. See [this](http://www.highvoltageconnection.com/articles/highvoltagespacing.pdf) reference which has pointers to standards documents.

Creepage distance is another matter- it depends more on the environmental conditions and will be larger than the distance through air.

Comment: here is also some NASA doc with a table in the end: http://misspiggy.gsfc.nasa.gov/tva/markfan/condspcing.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Clearance and creepage are two very different things when talking about withstand voltage

I am just pointing this out just incase you are using creepage and clearance interchangeably, especially as you are referring to connectors and thus creepage may be what you are really interested in.

[image]

Assuming you are really after **clearance**  the shortest point to point distance, through air:  The british standard: BS EN 60064-1 :2007 is a very good reference point to capture the point of inception with regards to corona discharge.

For an Inhomogeneous field, two conductors 15.2mm apart will have a corona inception voltage at 10kVdc

For a Homogeneous field, two conductors 3.5mm apart will have a corona inception voltage at 10kVdc.

These are subject to altitude correction factors.

**NOTE**: This is the point of inception and thus to actually safely support this voltage, additional clearance must be added on top of this. This is application & local working practice specific.